# Java car license plate with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a regex representation of license plates in my country:

Pattern for example:

[L{L}][NN{N}][LLL]

More examples:

BH 23 MAS

AG 33 TRA

When we have two letters here [L{L}] we cannot have three numbers in the middle,only two

When we have only a letter here [L{L}] we can have only 'B' and we can have two or three numbers in the middle:

B 12 ERT

B 123 ERT

And at the end for every case: with one letter or two letters at beginning we cannot have 'I' or 'O' on the first or last position in the [LLL] from the final of the expression.(B 123 OST-is false 'O' being first and here BC 12 SEI-is false because 'I' is in the last position)

Any ideas how a regex for this would look like?

Comment: Please format your question properly. This increases chances for getting an answer!

Comment: You can OR your cases together with this symbol: `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [L{L}][NN{N}][LLL]
>
> When we have two letters here [L{L}] we cannot have three numbers in the middle,only two

```regex
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}
```

> When we have only a letter here [L{L}] we can have only 'B' and we can have two or three numbers in the middle:

```regex
B[0-9]{2,3}
```

> We cannot have 'I' or 'O' on the first or last position in the [LLL]

```regex
[A-HJ-NP-Z][A-Z][A-HJ-NP-Z]
```

Combine them using `^(?:A|B)C$`, and allowing 1 space between parts

```regex
^(?:B ?[0-9]{2,3}|[A-Z]{2} ?[0-9]{2}) ?[A-HJ-NP-Z][A-Z][A-HJ-NP-Z]$
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mbLtMm/1) for demo.

Comment: Thanks for this!This really helps me.